# OPAM doesn't recognize the create subcommand

Tags: ocaml, opam

In following these instructions: https://ocaml.org/docs/install.html#Ubuntu-Ubuntu-19-04

when I ran

```
eval opam env
```

it responds with the message

```
opam: unknown command `env`.
```

when I run `opam switch create 4.08.0` it responds

```
opam: Invalid switch subcommand "create"
```

I've just done a fresh install of the latest version of Linux Mint, installed OPAM with `apt` and also used it to install OCaml.

Answer (score 4):

I used this:
http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#Binary-distribution

to reinstall opam, that fixed opam. but utop is still broken.

Comment: I wonder why the answer is still not accepted

Comment: Worked for me. Pasting the command here in case it becomes a dead link one day:
bash -c "sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)"